# equivalent [UIPopoverController setContentViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL)]; for iOS8

Tags: size, ios8, xcode6, uipopovercontroller

what's the proper way to set UIPopoverController size in iOS8

in iOS7 was

```
[UIPopoverController setContentViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL)];
```

but now it doesn't work

thanks in advance

---

**EDIT:** Gonna put my piece of code here and both results (iOS7.1 and iOS8)

```
DetalleTarjetaVC *controller     = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetalleTarjetaVC"];

            UINavigationController                      *navController;
            navController                               = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
            navController.toolbarHidden                 = FALSE;
            navController.navigationBar.translucent     = FALSE;
            navController.toolbar.translucent           = FALSE;
            navController.navigationBar.barTintColor    = UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(toolbarTintColor, 0.95);
            navController.navigationBar.barStyle        = UIBarStyleBlack;
            navController.toolbar.barTintColor          = UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(toolbarTintColor, 0.95);
            navController.toolbar.barStyle              = UIBarStyleBlack;



            controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(0XFFFFFF, 1);

            tarjetasPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];


            CGRect rect     = button.frame;
            CGPoint coord   = [button convertPoint:button.frame.origin toView:self.tableView];
            rect.origin.y   = coord.y -20;

            [tarjetasPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(530, 400) animated:YES];
            [tarjetasPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect
                                             inView:self.view
                           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
                                           animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's something that may help you

```
        int iOSVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion] intValue];

        if (iOSVersion >= 8) {
            controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(530, 312);
        }
        else{
            [tarjetasPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(530, 400) animated:YES];
        }
```

I reduced in 88.0 height for iOS8 since you have to consider the width of your toolbar and navigation controller (44px each) for getting same size

Answer (score 0):

The method have not been replaced in iOS8. You just need to alloc an istance before, like that:

```
 UIPopoverController *yourPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] init];
```

and then you can use:

```
 [yourPopoverController setContentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Or easily you can pass the viewController on UIPopoverController Init:

```
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:yourViewController];
```

Hope it help.